# Output scrape results into multiple .csv files, with python, BeautifulSoup, pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping links from multiple pages under multiple searches and want to output scraped results into multiple .csv files. The table shows the .csv file which lists both my source urls and desired output file names:

| url | outputfile |
| --- | --- |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/search/results.asp?categoryid=230&qtype=2&publisher=IDCs&datepub=0&submit2=Search | outputPS1xIDC.csv |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/search/results.asp?categoryid=90&qtype=2&publisher=IDC&datepub=0&submit2=Search | outputPS2xIDC.csv |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/search/results.asp?categoryid=233&qtype=2&publisher=IDC&datepub=0&submit2=Search | outputPS3xIDC.csv |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/search/results.asp?categoryid=169&qtype=2&publisher=IDC&datepub=0&submit2=Search | outputPS4xIDC.csv |

Now, with the code below, I managed to read the urls in sequence and the rest of the code also works well (when I specify the output filename directly). However, it only outputs the last of the 4 pages in the list, so it overwrites the result each time. What I actually want for it is to output the results from the first url to the first outputfile, second to second, etc.
(Of course my actual list of source URLs is much longer than these 4).

Please help, especially with the last line, as clearly just writing [outputs] there doesn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('inputs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    urls = [row["url"] for row in reader]
    outputs = [row["outputfile"] for row in reader]

    data = []

    for url in urls:

        def scrape_it(url):
            page = requests.get(url, headers={'Cookie': 'ResultsPerPage=100'})
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            nexturl = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1]['href']
            stri = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1].string
            reports = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": ["SearchTableRowAlt", "SearchTableRow"]})

            for report in reports:
                data.append({
                    'title': report.find('a', class_='linkTitle').text,
                    'price': report.find('div', class_='resultPrice').text,
                    'date_author': report.find('div', class_='textGrey').text.replace(' | published by: TechNavio', ''),
                    'detail_link': report.a['href']
                })

            if 'next' not in stri:
                print("All pages completed")
            else:
                scrape_it(nexturl)


    scrape_it(url)
    myOutput = pd.DataFrame(data)
    myOutput.to_csv([outputs], header=False) #works (but only for the last url) if instead of [outputs] I have f'filename.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Pandas, and I don't really want to run your input, but a couple of things jump out a me when I look at your code:

1. It looks like you are ***not*** looping over `url` and `output` ***together***.  It looks like you loop over all the URLs, and then after all those loops you write once.
2. Likewise, `data` is just having the HTML table data appended and appended, it's never reset for each individual URL.

Without being able to run this, I recommend something like this.  The scraping is fully encapsulated and separate from the loop, and as such you can now more clearly see the flow of inputs and outputs:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd


def scrape_it(url, data):
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'Cookie': 'ResultsPerPage=100'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    nexturl = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1]['href']
    stri = soup.find_all(class_="standardLinkDkBlue")[-1].string
    reports = soup.find_all("tr", {"class": ["SearchTableRowAlt", "SearchTableRow"]})

    for report in reports:
        data.append({
            'title': report.find('a', class_='linkTitle').text,
            'price': report.find('div', class_='resultPrice').text,
            'date_author': report.find('div', class_='textGrey').text.replace(' | published by: TechNavio', ''),
            'detail_link': report.a['href']
        })

    if 'next' in stri:
        data = scrape_it(nexturl, data)
    
    return data


with open('inputs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    urls = [row["url"] for row in reader]
    outputs = [row["outputfile"] for row in reader]

    for (url, output) in zip(urls, outputs):  # work on url and output together
        data = scrape_it(url, [])
        myOutput = pd.DataFrame(data)
        myOutput.to_csv(output, header=False)
```

Comment: It does exactly what I needed! It's amazing you can do that without even running this code! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! I've had a really good teacher who emphasized being able to read code, and I could read the *structure* was off. :) Cheers!

Comment: Oh, wait! I just realized this won't work for pages with more than 100 results.

Comment: thank so much for further work on this. However, I'm not sure what's going on now - it completes with exit code 0, but doesn't produce any csv files with any data. So I'll review and check it line by line tomorrow, to see at which step any problem might lie (as the debugger doesn't find anything).

Comment: Hey, no problem. I enjoy trying to help :) I'm not sure what your comfort level is with any of this. I went ahead and made [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/044cc471403f504cdc8adf75225d87f2) to try explain how to handle scraping till there isn't anything left to scrape. Maybe that will be clearer, taken out of the bigger picture, with simple examples.

Comment: Zach, thank you for the gist. I read that. I think you should do youtube or something, because you're trying to explain the principles, while a lot of videos there are totally geared to specific examples, which don't work for other applications. I'm very much a beginner, but I follow the above and your gist. At the moment, at my wit's end. I tried with the exact copy of your code above, and it doesn't work. (Just returns "Process finished with exit code 0" very quickly with no other output. I tried modifying it by adding "data = []" in scrape_it and before it. Tried without 'return data'....

Comment: . and tried with various other permutations. I also tried your earlier version, where you did not add data as a parameter for scrape_it, with a number of permutations, and I cannot get back to a version that I think worked. (I think I added 'data = []' to make your earlier version work. But to no avail...